# Runtime error occasionally interrupts my Python script

Tags: python, debugging, runtime-error, runtime, blackmagic-fusion

I seem to be getting a Runtime error whilst running my Python script in Blackmagic Fusion.

```
# "The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way".
```

This does not happen every time I run the script. It only seems to pop up when I feed the Python script a heavy workload, or if I run the Python script multiple times inside of the Blackmagic Fusion compositing software, without restarting the package. I thought this might be a memory leak, but when I check the CPU memory usage, it does not seem to flinch at all.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this, or at least a solution of how I might start to debug the script?

Many thanks.

Comment: You should post the code and the [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace).

Answer (score 1):

if you know how to get runtime error, then run your script using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this'll help.  It's apparently a common error with microsoft visual c++:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884538